# Upload Multiple files to SQL database using asp File upload with AllowMultiple="True"

Tags: asp.net, sql, file, upload

I have an asp application with an asp FileUpload Control and a button name "upload" 
however, FileUpload Control only allows one file to be uploaded on SQL server, through research, I have found out that FileUpload has an attribute of AllowMultiple="True" which allows users to select multiple files by using the asp FileUpload Control,

what I want to know is, how will the files selected be uploaded to SQL server table by clicking the upload button, need quick solution thanks!!!

Comment: If you need a quick response, you'll need to make sure there is sufficient upstream capacity on your connection. On the server itself, ensure it has sufficient memory and CPU to handle the processing. As to how the files will be uploaded, they will be transferred in a binary fashion.

Comment: I'm new to asp, and just saw that FileUpload Control has the AllowMultiple attribute, I can upload a single file to the database but I can't make it work when I have selected multiple files

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to use: FileUpload.PostedFiles

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile upFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
    SaveFiles(upFile);
}

private void SaveFiles(HttpPostedFile fObj)
{
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))// set ConnectionString
   {
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DatabaseQuery,con)) // set appropriate query
       {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", ReadFile(fObj));
          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
}

private byte[] ReadFile(HttpPostedFile fObj2)
{
    byte[] data = new Byte[fObj2.ContentLength];
    fObj2.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: YES... make sure you have your control something like this: <asp:FileUpload ID="MyFileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />